# method in android which can be accessed from anywhere?like modules in VB

Tags: android

I am new to android. If my question is wrong please forgive me,

My Question is:

Can I write a method in android which can be accessed from anywhere inside my application?

I've studied VB for all these years and now I am trying to program in android, I couldn't stop comparing them when I write code.

In VB we can create modules and access it from anywhere. Is there anything I can do in Android...??

Answers and advises are needed!

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB. It sounds like you either want static methods in Java, or to create an Android Service.

Comment: I want to create Public methods to make them available to the **rest of my application components**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a class with a static method:

```
public class MyClass {

        public static void myMethod() {
            // Your code here...
        }

}
```

And you can call it like this:  MyClass.myMethod();

Comment: ThankYou for the answer .Can I access it from any class inside my whole application by calling 'MyClass.myMethod' ? Why it is static?

Comment: Yes,you can call MyClass.myMethod() where you want in your whole application, you just need to import the needed package. Static means : "the same for all this type of class". If you define a static String, if you modify it in one object of this class, this string is modified for all objects typeof MyClass.

Comment: I've Got it running!! Thanks a lot :for the answer,and for the Quick reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try extending Application and put your common functions there.

In all activities you can access this via context.

For reference follow this:

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: The link is down

Answer (score 0):

It is a long topic to discuss , but as you have simply ask whether method is accessible or not  , then answer is yes but with some respect of java rules.

Android is again like java coding, You can do same thing what we can do with java.

- Same Data type
- Method Format
- Class structure
- Inheritance, Public , private , protected, etc.

So while you write your code you should care for that all things and these all thing you know because you are working in VB.

Comment: Thanks chintan khetiya ,I think I have to stop comparing and make use of things available in android language!! :)

Answer (score 0):

VB module equivalent is not there in java(android),
but some how you can mock them to some extend by using final classes with static methods.
Anyway you need to import the package containing these type of classes wherever you use it.